# Too deep or too deeply

Tags: adverbs

A Text from a recent (excellent) Dr.Who episode:

> "One day you will linger in the same place too long.
>   You will sit too still or sleep too deep - and when, too late, you rise to go, you will notice a second shadow next to yours. Your life will then be over."

To sit "still-ly" isn't possible, I know, "still" is used as the adverb here, but what about the "deep"? Is there a difference between "sleep too deep" or "sleep too deeply"? Why isn't the adverb used here?

Comment: Deeply is also a synonym for intensely, so it *can* have a different meaning than deep. The idiom would be: out cold.

Answer (score 1):

*deep* is used as an adverb. See [***deep***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/deep):

> **adverb**
>
> 21) in a deep way or to a deep extent; far down, far in, far back, etc."   ⇒ *to dig deep*"

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation of the use of **deeply** as the appropriate **-ly** adverb in your example is well founded as a modifier for **sleep**

> He slept **deeply**

meaning that he had a **deep sleep**.

However, there are a few other things going on:

**Dr. Who** is a very **stylized** programme on BBC1 and I believe it is with this **aesthetic** that the text is **coloured**.  The excerpt is **poetic in nature**: too long, too still, too deep, too late. That life is full of **stationary** time: linger, sit, sleep. That by **actively** being too **inactive**, we have not risen to the challenges, nor grasped the opportunities, nor **fully embraced** all the life has to offer. That in this way, life **creeps at a petty pace**. That when we finally do **rouse** ourselves, it is **too late**, and then we **exit**.

The allusion of the **second shadow** is that of the Grim Reaper **when our time is over**.  Where as in life, one faces and moves **toward the light**, at this point we are facing **away** from the light. How else would we be able to **notice the second shadow**?

To maintain the cadence of sit/still, sleep/deep only **single syllable** words are used, **deeply** would break this **poetic cadence**. Then also consider if it is really possible to **sit too still** or **sleep too deep**? A possible alternative might be

> ...sit motionlessly or sleep heavily...

but it would not have the same **feel** or **rythm** as the original.

In your example, **deep** is used as an **adverb**, though it is **not usually** used in this way. It is because the verb, **sleep**, is being used in an ***active*** sense: **wilfully sleeping too much**.

**Dr. Who** is an **English programme**. Please do remember it is **their language**.